# Chrome extension keep animating the icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension which has a dynamic icon. That is when I can click on start button, the icon animation starts.

Currently to check that if its working I am just incrementing a variable value and displaying it as a badget text.

```
          // timeout variable    -------->    // think of better way to avoid global variable
            var isRunning = false; // semaphore variable to make sure only one instance of the function is running
            var t = 0;   
            var test_clock = function(message){
                var i = 0;
                var myLoop = function() {
                    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: 'project_timesheet_synchro/static/src/img/icon.png' });
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
                        'text': '' + (i++),
                    });
                }
                if (!isRunning && message == "start") {     // if not running           
                    //if(message == "start"){
                        isRunning = true;
                        t = setInterval(function () { myLoop() }, 1000);  // keep animating till clearInterval() is called in stop()
                    //}
                }
                else if (message == "stop") {   // to stop the clock animation loop
                    clearInterval(t);
                    isRunning = false;
                    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: 'project_timesheet_synchro/static/src/img/icon.png' });
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
                        'text': '',
                    });
                }
            }
```

As soon as I close the popup the icon stops animating.
I want to continue animating when the popup is closed.

How can I manage it to run in the background.I have not added the popup html as I am sure there is no problem in it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a [persistent background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)

Comment: @IvánNokonoko        thanks for the answer